# How to prevent or a workaround to prevent flutter setState changing the value of a form field that is previously entered by the user

Tags: flutter

My form field consist of several textfield and one combobox

The issue here is when the user entered data in the textfield and after that changing combobox value where setState is called making the whole form resetted with the initial data.

The user submit the form but the textfield already reverted to the initial value not the one that the user entered

[image]

In the code when before the combobox changed and setState is called I already captured all the textfield value, the one the user just newly entered:

[image]

as shown in the code above, resetting the textfield value after the setState is not working, the form textfield still using the initial value after the form reload because of the setState. The initial value here is the original data from /get by id at the backend restful api. Please help, thank you in advance.

Edit

This is the screenshot where I attach the controller to the TextField

[image]

Comment: 1. Just use "key" & initialValue  Or  2. Form( key: ..... ) to ur TextField.

Answer (score 0):

There's high change that you forgot to attach your `TextEditingController` to your `TextField/TextFormField`. I never seen the case that text value is disappear when we call `setState`. And you don't need intermediate variables like name, phone... - just use directly `textEditingController.text`. This is my hypothesis base on your information. **PLEASE PROVIDE** more about your text field code stuff.

Comment: I update the question, I already attach the controller variable to the textfield controller

Comment: is it possible to change the combobox value, the global variable dropdownValue without using setState, so that it will not refresh the form?